# Rename and copy/move sets of similar named directories to another location

Tags: linux, shell, directory, recursive

For a set of directories with similar names at different location,

`/foldX/dirA` with sub-directories `aa1 aa2 aa3 aa4 aa5`

`/foldZ/dirA` with sub-directories `aa1 aa2 aa3`

`/foldY/dirA` with sub-directories `aa1 aa2 aa3`

What could be an efficient way to copy or move the directories `aa*` to another folder, 
`/foldNew/dirA`, as `aa1, aa2, aa3, aa4, aa5, aa6, aa7, aa8, aa9, aa10` ?

`aa1` to `aa4` from `foldX`

`aa5` to `aa7` from `foldY`

`aa8` to `aa10` from `foldZ`

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Do you want to merge contents of similarly named directories or not? What do you mean by "efficient"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script does what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
mkdir foldNew
for i in fold?/dirA/aa*; do
    counter=$((counter + 1))
    mv $i foldNew/aa$counter
done
```

It keeps count of how many folders it moved already, and it uses Bash's wildcard system to iterate over all the folders you want to move.

I tested it with the setup you described, and it did what you wanted, with the only exception that it moved them to aa1 through aa11, because dirA has five subdirectories, not four.

That script moves aa20 earlier than aa3. If the order of the subdirectories really matters, you can try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
mkdir foldNew
for i in $(echo fold?/dirA/aa* | sort -V); do
    counter=$((counter + 1))
    mv $i foldNew/aa$counter
done
```

I think that it doesn't handle spaces and newlines in filenames well, however, so be careful if you use it.

Comment: thanks. can you chek wheter this will work if number of directories are more than 9? e.g.  'aa1, aa2, ... aa15'. 
I tried but it seems after taking 9 directories from foldX, its switching to foldY

Comment: Replacing ? by * should work. "?" matches one character, "*" can match multiple. I'll change it.

Comment: Thank you.
Further, as I expected (learning from my past codes), for more than 10 subdirectories, e.g 20, the code copies or moves /foldA/aa10 as /foldNew/aa2
This may be because when it seach for subdirectories inside foldA/DirA, it read them as aa1, aa10, aa11, ...aa19, aa2, aa20, aa3, aa4....aa9 
any thought on how to overcome this?

Comment: `sort -V` is capable of that kind of sorting. I added an alternative script. It might do weird things when there are spaces in the filenames, so watch out.

Comment: Thanks ! But, it seems sort -V is not helping out here.